# How to solve $a^x=x\,(\text{mod } 10^{12})$

Tags: number-theory

For given $1< a< 50001$, I want to find $x$ for which $a^x=x ~(\text{mod }10^{12})$.

My idea is to find $x_1$:  $a^{x_1} = x_1~ (\text{mod } 2^{12})$ and $x_2$: $a^{x_2} = x_2 ~(\text{mod } 5^{12})$ and then calculate $x$ where $x=a^x ~(\text{mod } 10^{12})$ using the Chinese remainder theorem.

It is quite easy to find $x_1$, but I have an issue with calculating $x_2$.

$$a^n = \underbrace{a*a*a*…*a}_{n\text{ times}}$$

$$2^3 = 2*2*2$$

$$a^x=x ~(\text{mod } 10^{12})   \Longleftrightarrow  a^x ~(\text{mod } 10^{12})  =  x ~(\text{mod }10^{12})$$

$$3^2 = 1 ~(\text{mod } 2) \Longleftrightarrow   3^2 ~(\text{mod } 2) = 1 ~(\text{mod } 2)$$

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem